# Australian plug on 220v pump

Tags: electrical

I purchased a pump that is 220v 60 hz and is wired with an australian plug.  The vendor said simply to replace with an American 220v plug.  I cut off the australian plug and it only has 3 wires.  I cant determine where to attach the 2 hot 110v?  Does anyone have any experience with this?
Thank you

Comment: *Which* American 240V plug did you get? NEMA 6? NEMA 10? NEMA 14?

Comment: Perhaps this diagram of an Australian socket helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/NZS_3112#/media/File:Australian_Socket-Outlet,_Auto_Switched.jpg

Comment: What color wires are there, and which went to which pin of the original plug?

Comment: I am using Nema 6 plug and I believe I wire my 2 hot to their Brown and Blue and Their green and yellow to ground?  Thank you

Comment: That is a straight 220 v. So the brown blue to the hot legs then the green to ground will work.

Answer (score 2):

In North America (+Colombia, Ecuador) we use 240v center-tapped for 120V on either side.  In the rest of the world, they use 220-240V straight, no center tap.

For us, conventional household plug/socket is the 120V, and it has a name, NEMA 5.

There's also plug/socket  which supports 240V only, omitting the center tap.   This is called NEMA 6.  It looks nearly identical, but is *keyed* differently so it can't accidentally be plugged into a NEMA 5.

He is saying use a NEMA 6 plug.

NEMA 6 plugs come in several styles rated for 15 amps, 20A or 30A.  Use one that is correct for the power draw of your appliance, and the manufacturer can tell you which one they recommend, or search/ask a new question. If a 15A plug is correct, but you have a 30A socket conveniently available, do not put a 30A plug on it.  If you have that problem, search/ask a new question.

There are also other plug/sockets intended for devices which need *both* 120V and 240V, and provide the center tap (neutral) as well.  As long as they provide ground (NEMA 14), you could use one of those instead, or you could use NEMA 6 and an adapter cable.

If your house does not have any NEMA 6 sockets, that is fixable, ask a new question.

Comment: It depends on the load most motor loads are straight 220/240 no neutral.

Answer (score 1):

The [mapping of Australian plug terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/NZS_3112) to wires is straightforward:

[image]

For use with North American power, wire the Aussie "neutral" to be the other U.S. "hot".  So connect the red to red, black to black, and green (or bare)  to ground.

Comment: I did not catch "the other hot" in the description my bad will delete the comment.